# How to hide status bar with animation in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

Since iOS 7 rolled out, I can't show or hide status bar with animation just like in iOS 6.
For now I use NSTimer to control it when to hide.

here is my code:

```
- (void)hideStatusBar{
    _isStatusBarHidden=YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
- (void)showStatusBar{
_isStatusBarHidden=NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
    //===================
 _controlVisibilityTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(hideStatusBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
```

But unfortunately the way of status bar hiding seems a little bit rough, not fading away. Is someone out there has a solution to this ?

## Update

I solved the hiding issue, using @hahaha solution. I just need a view to be the background of the status bar, here is my code.

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

self.StatusBarOrange = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, appDelegate.window.frame.size.width, 20)];    
[self.StatusBarOrange setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.StatusBarOrange];
```

and now everything works perfectly!

Comment: +1 for updating with your final solution! thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to call

```
[UIViewController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

from within an animation block as in the following example:

```
@implementation SomeViewController {
    BOOL _statusBarHidden;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return _statusBarHidden;
}

- (void)showStatusBar:(BOOL)show {
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _statusBarHidden = !show;
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: It's amazing you know this, thanks!  It seems that setStatusBarHidden:YES essentially does NOTHING in iOS5.  Thanks again.