# How can I place a UIWindow behind another UIWindow?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwindow

I have 2 `UIWindows`, when I show both `UIWindows` the latest shown `UIWindow` always is above the 1st shown `UIWindow`. Each `UIWindow` is an own `UIWindow`, so no `Subview`.

Does anyone know how i can place a `UIWindow` behind another `UIWindow`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using two UIWindows and not UIViewController as a subview to the first window?

Comment: @NikosM. Yep, the windows are over the status bar

Comment: You can have a full screen UIViewController and hide the status bar.

Comment: @NikosM. No, not on iOS 7

Comment: Yes, you can. Put this in the viewcontroller you want the status bar hidden. `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}`

Comment: @NikosM. Wow, great. Can you animate this, so it moves in and out?

Comment: There is a solution but I haven't give it a try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185347/how-to-hide-status-bar-with-animation-in-ios-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I suspect there's probably a cleaner, more maintainable way to achieve what you want, you should be able to manipulate the order windows appear using the `windowLevel` property - although to be honest the last time I tried to do this was on iOS 5 so maybe that's changed. But generally you'd do something like:

```
windowToPlaceInFront.windowLevel = windowToPutInBack.windowLevel + 1.0f;
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot have multiple UIWindow inside an app.

From Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html):

> Unless an app can display content on an external device screen, an app has only one window.

Comment: I never tried indeed, but since it is not the normal use of window, it may not work anymore on last iOS