# How to fade status bar in and out of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, fade, statusbar

In my app, the UI fades in and out when you shake the phone using the following code:

```
- (void)showButton:(UIButton*)xButton {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{xButton.alpha = 1.0;}
                 completion:nil];
}
```

I am also using this code to make the status bar hidden:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {return YES;}
```

However, how can I have the status bar fade in and out using the same animation as I do for the rest of the UI? All help appreciated.

Edit: Though a fade would be ideal, if it is not possible, I would be able to settle for the status bar simply being shown and hidden ("popping" in and out).

Comment: May be this can help you with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361296/1898973.

Comment: Success! Thanks man :) I had already searched all over, but had somehow not come across this answer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941774/how-to-fade-out-the-status-bar-while-not-hiding-it